# how to set a p tag inside a div and the div tag inside a td tag

Tags: jquery, html

thanks in advance for reviewing my post.

I've only been using jquery for about a week now and so far, it's pretty neat.  It seems I'm stuck though.  I have a table with the following structure:

For example, I have a table with an id as "mytable".
Rows with the following cells:

- A td with a div tag. The div tag has a p tag with an id as "myP1"
- A td with a div tag. The div tag has a p tag with an id as "myP2"

Nothing I do seems to work?  How can I set the html inside the "p" tags?  This didn't seem to work:

```
//note:  the key would match one of the ids in the "p" tags.
jQuery.each( map, function( key, value ) {
    $( '#mytable td' ).find( 'p[id=' + key + "]'" ).html( value );
    //this did not work either -->  $('#' + key ).html( value );
});
```

Thanks inadvance for your help!

Comment: Please paste the HTML code so that we don't have to render it all in our heads.

Comment: if the key matches the `P` id, code should work...what does `map` look like?

Comment: `$('#' + key )` &  `find( 'p[id=' + key + "]'" )` didn't work because your id names are not just a number.  The question is, is the "key" in your map variable object/array an index number or is it actually a string like "myP1"?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's quick response (it's nice to know there are helpful people around)!!!  I actually tried to paste my HTML but got an error.  This is my first post on this site so I'm not sure what I didn't do right when I tried to copy my HTML code into my post?  Unfortunately, none of the recommendations are working.  Since my JSP has grown quite a bit, I'm going to try and pull together a small example of what I'm doing...perhaps while doing this I'll discover my issue.

Comment: After pulling a small example together, I could now see that this issue was related to the data in the collection.  Thanks again for everyone's feedback!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this is jquery method for window.onload = function ...
$(function() {
    // this tells jQuery to get the element with the ID "myP1" and fill it's text with what's in () of .text
    $("#myP1").text('Type a string here and it will be the text')
});
```

as for the rest of your answer, i think:

```
$(function(){
    $.each(map, function(i, data){ // i is 0 based index, or could be key 
                                   // in object like var map = { key1: 'value1' }
        $("#myP"+(i+1)).text(data);
    ​});
});
```

**[here is a working example with even more fun uses of jQuery, will add comments to it and update it shortly](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Wn579/)**

Answer (score 1):

To update all p tags inside a div in that table, you can do this

```
$(function(){

  $("#mytable div p").html("dynamic content");    

});
```

​Here is the working sample

http://jsfiddle.net/2gWHW/3/

If you want to upload only a specific p, you can use the Id of that like this

```
$("#myP1").html("new content");
```

Comment: @sasims : Did you check the link where i posted a sample ? I guess you have some other script error then. Use firebug to see what error it is showing in the console tab